# Does listIterator.next() return deep copy or shallow copy?

Tags: java, deep-copy

I have following piece of code:

```
ListIterator iterator = resultSet.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   Object[] data = (Object[]) iterator.next();

}
```

I just want to know whether iterator.next() method returns deep copy of next item in the `resultSet` or shallow?

Comment: That would depend on what's the type of `resultSet`.

Comment: @Eran I think it's pretty safe to assume that `resultSet` is a `List`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But we can't assume which List implementation it is (though no implementation I know of returns a deep copy, it doesn't mean there are no such implementations).

Comment: `ListIterator` is just an interface, so how it behaves behind the scenes, fully depends on implementation.

Comment: @Eran I guess that's fair, since both are interfaces, and it does not look like the interface docs would limit the designers to returning a reference. The only hint that returning a reference to the actual object is assumed comes from the doc on the `next()` method, which says that repeated calls to `next()`/`previous()` will return the same object. Since they do not say which "same" object it has to be, an implementation could potentially return the same copy.

Comment: down voters care to explain the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `resultSet` is a `List` implementation from the standard Java library, the answer to the "deep or shallow copy" question is "neither". `ListIterator`s of `List` classes in the standard Java library do not return a copy; they returns a *reference*, so you access the object stored in the `List`, not a copy of it.

Since Java arrays are mutable, any modifications that your loop makes to `data` are done on the `Object[]` array stored inside the list.

As [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran) correctly notes in his comment, since `List` and `ListIterator` are only interfaces, it is entirely conceivable to come up with an implementation that returns copies of list elements rather than references to actual elements. These copies could be deep or shallow, depending on your own implementation. However, list implementations supplied by Java library always return references to actual list elements.